# HTML repetitive blocks

Tags: html

I wish to do the following things:

- Insert external html blocks into new html pages
- Use the same html header from one html file for a number of pages, without recreating the header again for all the pages

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[HTML Imports](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/)** which is part of **[Web Components](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/explainer/):**

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="/path/to/your/file.html">
</head>
```

If your page does not have to be pure HTML, you should consider using PHP or a similar server-side language.

Comment: I wasn't aware of HTML Imports. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I have actually bookmarked this page because of your answer, there is a lot I can learn from it Peter!

Comment: It's just some code I have working on a site. It needs going over and fixing up after I made on-the-fly modifications to it to try to make it more basic and suit the question asked so I wouldn't treat is as gospel just yet, but I hope it at least proves useful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about appears to be a process called templating. There are many ways to do this, including writing Javascript to insert pre-written HTML templates into the DOM (the webpage). You might also consider using a pre-written templating library such as http://handlebarsjs.com/ or another library which contains templating functions like http://underscorejs.org/. A simple MVC guide like:

http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/a-beginners-guide-to-mvc-for-web.html

May be helpful too, to get you started.

In a more practical sense, here's one possible solution:

To begin I would recommend putting the 'blocks' you want to insert in a separate folder. In the website I run, for example, I place them in the \templates folder (or subfolders) but you can more or less call it what you want as long as it makes sense to you. For our purposes let's say we've created block.html and put it in our \templates subfolder...

Now, within each template you will have whatever you want to load in; something like this:

```
<h2>Title of section</h2>
<p>My text.</p>
```

Or whatever you'd like. Then, you'll probably want to add an element to your main page which calls some Javascript, which loads your HTML template in when a particular condition occurs. For example, if you wanted to load in our block.html file you might write something like this:

```
<div id="calling-block" onclick="menuClicked('locationToInsert', 'block')"></div>
```

Which would call a Javascript function called 'menuClicked()' when we click the div with the id 'calling-block'.

Within the function we would write something like this:

```
<script>
    function menuClicked(insertEl, UrlString, onTemplateLoaded) {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(insertEl).innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        if (onTemplateLoaded) onTemplateLoaded();
    };
  };
  console.log(UrlString);
  xhttp.open("GET", UrlString, true);
  xhttp.send();
};
</script>
```

This is a very simple way of doing things and I'm sure people will tell you there are problems with it, so I would definitely recommend doing your own reading as well, but I hope this covers the very basics.

Comment: i want it only in HTML way. Kindly suggest

Comment: I've updated with the simplest explaination I can give off the top of my head. I hope it helps. If you find anything that doesn't seem right or you'd like explained further or in a different way I'd be more than happy to help. Just tell me what you're having trouble understanding or what additional things you need to cover and I'll do my best to work something out.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options, depends on you:

1) use iframes (a lot problems with responsibility) http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

2) ajax call in javascript, load external resource and then print it in placeholder tag (example is with jquery) http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp

3) use some server language/preprocessor (php, ruby, nodejs), depend if you can (need to by installed on server)

4) also there are static page generator, you add marks in your html, and they will compile html with marks to full static html http://hyde.github.io/ for example.

Answer (score -1):

You need tu use a server side functionality like php, aspx ...